# impdp stuck on index import

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, impdp

impdp import is stuck on:

> Processing object type
>   SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/FUNCTIONAL_INDEX/INDEX

How can you debug this?

Comment: Good blog post on debugging this issue. https://blog.toadworld.com/2018/06/07/impdp-hangs-or-appears-to-hang-but-has-it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During the impdp process, it doesn't import indexes, in fact it runs number of `CREATE INDEX` statements.

There could be various reasons of slow index creations such as inefficient PGA memory allocation and IO performance of underlying storage. Parallel(depending on available server resources-CPU,IO)  option could improve performance of index-creation.

> How can you debug this?

You can use the following query to check the status of the job.

```
 select * from dba_datapump_jobs;
```

Join `dba_datapump_sessions` with `v$session_wait` to know whether the impdp session is waiting for some resources.

Check alert log for possible error/warning messages.

Comment: To check the alert log: login to `sqlplus` >
`show parameter background`
and look for the `background_dump_dest` directory. There should be a log like `alert_XE.log`.

Answer (score 7):

It's not stuck. It just does not print every rebuilded index.
You can view status of the process using DBA_RESUMABLE.

> select * from dba_resumable;

Comment: I took a look at those suspended tasks and found that some indexes cannot be created because tablespace is full. Granting more space solve the problem.